# Hover on Jqgrid Column shows a tool-tip

Tags: jqgrid

I want to add a custom tooltip on jqgrid column headers.i hover over the column name and i get the tooltip(describes content related to that col)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is any built-in way to add custom headers. If you use the [headertitles](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aoptions) option, it will just use the text as the title attribute.

You'll probably have to set them manually doing something like this:

```
$("th[role='columnheader']").attr("title", "some description");
```

You can add that code to one of the callbacks such as `gridComplete`.

Comment: Right, this is the only way to do it at the moment. Such a feature would be a nice enhancement to the grid, though...

Comment: Yeah...one could also use one of the many jQuery tooltip plugins as well I suppose if he/she is very interested in custom tooltips.

Comment: @david Thanks a lot for your answer..! Right now its showing the same tooltip on the hover of every column..for specific tooltip i have to run a loop as in from first column to last column..ryt?

Comment: @Mindfreak -- possibly, but it will depend on exactly what you want the tooltips to display. Also, remember you can pass a function to the attr method: `attr("title", function(){...})`

Comment: @david Thanks ! i did the same way bt modified the code lil bit.Please see the answer below

Answer (score 0):

Thanks David for your answer.

we can do one more thing as shown in the code below :

var thd = jQuery("thead:first", grid[0].grid.hDiv)[0];
        jQuery("tr.ui-jqgrid-labels th:eq(" + columnnumber + ")", thd).attr("title","This column tells you about people who attended the training but missed the test");

if you want to show custome tooltip for all column you can probably add a loop from first column to last column and have the "text" in an array

var arr=["hello","bla bla","a ","b","c"];

and use this array in the loop